# post author if statement

Tags: author

Hi I'm try to get an if statement to work.

I want to display some HTML code if the post is created by a specific author.

This is what I'm come up with but it doesn't work.

```
<?php if ( get_posts ($post->ID, 'post_author', true) == '20')
  { ?>  HTML <?php } ?>
```

Thank You

Comment: In what context is this code to be used? Inside the loop? Outside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The `get_posts()` function retrieves posts from the database. If I understand you correctly, that's not what you want though, you simply mean to check the author of the post currently displayed.

You can simply use `$post->post_author`. If outside [the Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you have to call upon the `$post` global first.

Hence

```
global $post; // only required outside the loop

if ( 20 === $post->post_author ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Johannes that worked just need to add the ' to 20 to get '20'

Comment: The `$post_author` property of the `$post` object *should* be an integer and not a string, hence `20` *should* do. If you experience it differently though, then you must be right in adding the apostrophes. Alternatively, you could use `==` instead of `===` as a comparison operator, which is less strict does not check for variable type (`20 == '20'` returns `true` whereas `20 === '20'` returns `false`). If this helped you, you could mark this answer as correct (checkmark on the left hand).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're inside the loop, you can use [**`get_the_author()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author), which returns the Author **Display Name**:

```
if ( 'Author Display Name' == get_the_author() ) {
    // This post is written by the
    // specified author; do something
}
```

Note that `get_the_author()` accepts no parameters, and as such must be used from inside the Loop.